# Is there an implementation of a single instance blob store for Django?

Tags: django

I am new to Django so I apologize if I missed something.  I would like to have a library that gives me a single-instance data store for Blob / Binary data.   I want a library that masks whether or not the files are stored in the database, file system or some kind of back end like S3 on Amazon.  I want a single API that lets me add files, and get back URLs to serve those files.   Also it would be nice if the implementation supported some kind of migration if I had blobs in a database for a site when it just started out and then move those blobs to an S3 bucket behind the scenes without me needing to change how my application stores and serves the data.

An important sub-aspect of this is that the files have to be only shown to properly authorized users (i.e. just putting them in an open `/media/` folder as files is not sufficient).

Perhaps I am asking too much - but I find this kind of service very useful in my applications.  The main reason that I am asking is that unless I find such a thing - I will wander off and build my own library - I just don't want to waste the time if this kind of thing already exists.

Comment: Isn't that what the Django Storage class does? You can swap in different storages and all your code still works. I don't see difference with what you're asking. The authorization aspect is a different problem imo. What are the requirements? Are obfuscated links good enough? Or does every file request have to go through django to check the authorisation (meaning much larger load on your app server)?

Comment: This is an education application - obscured URLs are not enough.  The Storage class looks like a good start.  I think that my use cases can be a new implementation and/or a federation of several implementations under that API.  That is where I will start.  Thanks.

Comment: The django-filer package has a permissions system for file access. Might help with the access control.